# Set a default value to select

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to set a default value to ion-select option, On a radio button "No" is been clicked.

```
<ion-select class="brand" name="selectBrand" [(ngModel)]="selectBrand" required>
    <ion-option  *ngFor="let brand of Brand;" [value]="brand.val">{{brand.name}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>

<ion-col>
    <ion-list radio-group name="checkBox" [(ngModel)]="autoManufacturers">
         <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
                <ion-radio  [value]="true"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>No</ion-label>
            <ion-radio  (ionSelect)="radioChecked()" [value]="false"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

So when i click on "No" in radio button i need a default array [1] to be place.

```
 Brand = [
        {
            "name": "Avin",
            "val" : "Avin"
        },
        {
            "name": "Amul",
            "val" : "Amul"
        },
        {
            "name": "Arokya",
            "val" : "Arokya"
        },
        {
            "name": "Thirumala",
            "val" : "Thirumala"
        }];         



radioChecked(){
        console.log("hi");
   selectBrand = this.Brand[0];
}
```

When i try to do this i am getting empty value, could someone help me

Comment: use `this.selectBrand = this.Brand[0];`

Comment: if i use this.selectBrand i am getting error " 'Error'
message: 'Property 'selectBrand' does not exist on type 'MilkModifyDataPage'.'
at: '95,8'
source: 'ts'" @PierreDuc

Comment: Then I suggest you add that property to your component and don't use `name="selectBrand"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like [@PierreDuc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3106920/pierreduc) says in the comments, use a property from the page to hold the selected value, so you can initialize it with the default value.

**Component code:**

```
@Component({...})
export class YourPage {

  public selectedBrandValue: any;

  // ...

  constructor(...) {
    // Initialize the select with the first value by default
    this.selectedBrandValue = this.Brand[0].val;
  }

  // ...

}
```

**View:**

```
<ion-select class="brand" [(ngModel)]="selectedBrandValue" required>
    <ion-option  *ngFor="let brand of Brand;" [value]="brand.val">{{brand.name}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```